# Acquiring adjusted r-squared for a MixedModels.jl ::GeneralizedLinearMixedModel{Float64, Bernoulli{Float64}}

Tags: julia, mixed-models

I have fitted a genralized linear mixed model on the Bernoulli distribution via `MixedModels.jl`. I'd like to acquire a McFaddens' adjusted R squared term to complement the model description. I found `StatsBase.r2()` and `Statsbase.adjr2()` in the docs for MixedModelsExtras.jl (which is probably the wrong place to be looking), but am getting a method error.

```
MethodError: no method matching nullloglikelihood(::GeneralizedLinearMixedModel{Float64, Bernoulli{Float64}})
Closest candidates are:
  nullloglikelihood(::Union{StatsModels.TableRegressionModel, StatsModels.TableStatisticalModel}, ::Any...; kwargs...) at C:\Users\orr.kent\.julia\packages\StatsModels\6uCgU\src\statsmodel.jl:28
  nullloglikelihood(::GLM.LinearModel) at C:\Users\orr.kent\.julia\packages\GLM\P0Ris\src\lm.jl:205
  nullloglikelihood(::GLM.LmResp) at C:\Users\orr.kent\.julia\packages\GLM\P0Ris\src\lm.jl:95
```

Which suggests to me that I'm way out in left field seeking a function that can calculate a McFadden's adjusted R2 from a MixedModels object. Open to any and all hints in the right direction.

Comment: Not really an expert on R2, but from googling around, my hint is to use the formula `1.0 - ( deviance(fancymodel) / deviance(simplemodel) )`. So you will need to have a simple model. The `deviance` function is defined in `GLM.jl`. A simple model is a.k.a. a *null model* (but it usually includes a constant term).